# How to do a for loop with tidyverse verbs when the name of multiple data.frames are required?

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse

I have to rename multiple columns of multiple data.frames and I am using `rename_at` to do so. However, I am struggling to put the code into a for loop. I have data from 1992 to 2020 and replicate the following command:

```
base_92<- base_92 %>% rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with("_92")),.funs = funs(sub("[_]92$", "", .)))
base_93<- base_93 %>% rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with("_93")),.funs = funs(sub("[_]93$", "", .)))
base_94<- base_94 %>% rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with("_94")),.funs = funs(sub("[_]94$", "", .)))
```

and so on ...

```
   base_20<- base_20 %>% rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with("_20")),.funs = funs(sub("[_]20$", "", .)))
```

The problem for me is that I can not figure it out how to change the data.frame's name (e.g, `base_"year"`) as well as to change the name inside the `rename_at` command (e.g, `rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with("_year")),.funs = funs(sub("[_]year$", "", .))`)

I know that it might be obvious but I'm not able to figure out the solution. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Maybe a list of your data frames would be better suited?

Comment: Or you could use `as.name(paste0("base_" + year))` or `get` with the same name

Comment: @mhovd a list of data frame as an argument inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't quite sure how you wanted it, but here is a small, working example.
Notice how I use `get` to retrieve the dataframe with the name depending on year.

You could have this edit the dataframe directly, but I prefer to have my functions return so I can specify what I want saved where. Let me know if anything is unclear.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Example data
base_92 <- data.frame(val_92 = rnorm(10), type = sample(letters, 10), year = 92)
base_93 <- data.frame(val_93 = rnorm(10), type = sample(letters, 10), year = 93)
base_94 <- data.frame(val_94 = rnorm(10), type = sample(letters, 10), year = 94)
base_95 <- data.frame(val_95 = rnorm(10), type = sample(letters, 10), year = 95)
base_96 <- data.frame(val_96 = rnorm(10), type = sample(letters, 10), year = 96)
base_97 <- data.frame(val_97 = rnorm(10), type = sample(letters, 10), year = 97)


# Function to get dataframe
change_col_name <- function(year) {
  
  df_name = paste0("base_",year) # Paste the arguments together
  df = get(df_name) # Get the object with the specified name
  
  end_with_text = paste0("_",year) # Argument for vars
  sub_text = paste0("[_]",year,"$") # Argument for sub
  df %>% rename_at(.vars = vars(ends_with(end_with_text)),.funs = funs(sub(sub_text, "", .))) # Your modified code
}

# Returns the modified dataframe for base_92
change_col_name(92)

#>           val type year
#> 1  -0.4324551    i   92
#> 2   0.8831866    y   92
#> 3  -0.1493123    r   92
#> 4  -0.4115218    h   92
#> 5   0.6674991    n   92
#> 6   0.3123039    o   92
#> 7  -0.8335537    j   92
#> 8   0.9509300    s   92
#> 9   0.3138823    w   92
#> 10  2.6456262    x   92
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked out! And it is easy to put into a for loop @mohvd